# Django how to get one result using slicing queryset

Tags: python, django

I have to fetch the usernames of my authors' posts

Here the views.py:

```
from django.shortcuts import render, redirect, get_object_or_404
from django.http import HttpResponse
from django.forms import inlineformset_factory
from django.contrib.auth.forms import UserCreationForm
from django.contrib.auth.models import User
from django.contrib import messages
from django.contrib.auth import authenticate,login,logout
from django.contrib.auth.decorators import login_required
from django.utils import timezone

from .forms import CreateUserForm
from .models import Post
from .forms import PostForm

 def counter(request):
    authors = Post.objects.values_list('author', 'title')

    authors_id = Post.objects.values_list('author')
    authors_name = User.objects.get(id=authors_id)

    context = {'authors':authors, 'authors_name':authors_name}
    return render(request, 'account/counter.html', {'authors': authors})
```

My models.py is:

```
from django.db import models
from django.conf import settings
from django.utils import timezone

# Create your models here.

class Post(models.Model):
    author = models.ForeignKey(settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    title = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    text = models.TextField()
    created_date = models.DateTimeField(default=timezone.now)
    published_date = models.DateTimeField(blank=True, null=True)

    def publish(self):
        self.published_date = timezone.now()
        self.save()

    def __str__(self):
        return self.title
```

And here my forms.py:

```
from django.contrib.auth.forms import UserCreationForm
from django import forms
from django.contrib.auth.models import User

from .models import Post

class CreateUserForm(UserCreationForm):
    class Meta:
        model = User
        fields = ['username','email','password1','password2','user_permissions','is_staff','date_joined']

class PostForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Post
        fields = ['title', 'text', 'author']
```

Now the problem is that on 'authors_id' I have this Error: The QuerySet value for an exact lookup must be limited to one result using slicing, or if i get just one result value of the list the answer's error is: Field 'id' expected a number but got (3,).
So because it takes also the comma from 'values_list'.

**I've to got back each author's post and the title of each post the author wrote.**

How can I slice the queryset's list?

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
authors_id = Post.objects.values_list('author', flat=True)
authors_name = User.objects.get(id__in=authors_id)
```

or

```
authors_id = Post.objects.values_list('author', flat=True)[0]
authors_name = User.objects.get(id=authors_id)
```

Refer this https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/topics/db/queries/#the-pk-lookup-shortcut